# Techniques to detect Polymorphic and Metamorphic viruses?

Tags: antivirus, virus

What techniques can be applied to detect [Polymorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus#Polymorphic_code) and [Metamorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus#Metamorphic_code) viruses?

How difficult is to implement these techniques?

Are these techniques being applied in modern day anti-virus softwares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought most of the virus scanners nowadays use [*sandbox techniques*](http://www.norman.com/Virus/Sandbox/20374/en) to check for "bad" behavior. Therefore the polymorphic virusses will also be detected.
of course these detection techniques are also known to virus creators, and can easily be bypassed using a bunch of random, unharmfull, code executions before the actual payload.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossiable to detect all known poly/metamorphic bad-code.  White lists verification is the only provable technique.  It's not always possiable, especially if your infrastructure/computer has not been maintainedd very well.  Which is a good reason why signature, heuristic, emulation based detection is still valuable.